# Why is this method returning 0 no matter what the user inputs are?

Tags: java

The method `CountQiftPositiv` is returning `0` no matter what inputs I type.  What am I doing wrong here?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class QiftPositivCount 
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        final int SENTINEL = -9999;
        int x = 0;
        int count = 0;
        do 
        {
            System.out.print("Type numbers (-9999 to end) : ");
            x = scan.nextInt();
            if(x == SENTINEL)
            {
                break;
            }
            count++;
        }while (x != SENTINEL);

        if(count == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("You didnt type any number");
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("There are " + count + " numbers typed , and the numbers that fulfill the conditon are "
                               + CountQiftPositiv(x));
        }

    }

    private static int CountQiftPositiv(int nr)
    {
        int poz = 0;

        if(nr % 2 == 0 && nr % 3 == 0 && nr > 0)
        {
            poz++;
        }
        return poz;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `do`-`while` loop throws out *all* user input except the last integer entered (if any).  Since the only way out of that loop (not counting exceptions) is the sentinel value `-9999`, that is the *only* value you will ever assign to `x` and pass to `CountQiftPositiv`.

`CountQiftPositiv`, meanwhile, only returns `1` if for positive integers divisible by 6.  For every other value, including your sentinel, it returns `0`.

**Other Sentinel Problems**

The use of a sentinel value is almost always a mistake (unless that's specifically part of your assignment).  Sooner or later, that "impossible" input will actually show up.

Since your goal is to continue the loop until the user is done (a "yes or no" question), use a local Boolean variable, and test *that*.  Also, [`java.util.Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt--) has lots of useful methods for exactly this kind of situation, for example:

```
boolean done = false;
while (! done) {
    if (scan.hasNextInt()) {
        // Store scan.nextInt() for use later.  See below.
    } else {
        // No more (valid) inputs.
        done = true;
    }
}
```

*This* loop could actually be shortened to just `while (scan.hasNextint()) { ... }`, but storing your loop's continue-or-end condition in a variable is handy for more complex exit decisions.

**Storing User Input**

You aren't storing more than one user input, ever.  Create a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) of some sort to store them, and then operate on that list.

```
java.util.List<Integer> numbers = new java.util.LinkedList<Integer>();
```

Later, in the "while not done" loop:

```
if (scan.hasNextInt()) {
    numbers.add(scan.nextInt());
} else {
    done = true;
}
```

**Counting User Inputs**

No need for `count` --- your collection of integers will store that for you:

```
if (numbers.size() == 0) {
    System.out.println("You didn't type any numbers!");
}
```

**Printing Output**

Finally, output each number only if it fulfills that weird condition.  This assumes you rewrite `CountQiftPositiv` to return a `boolean` (which it almost does already):

```
for (int number : numbers) {
    if (CountQiftPositiv(number)) {
        System.out.println(number);
    }
}
```

You'll probably want to rename that method now that it no longer counts anything.

I leave the rest to you.

PS:  It's almost always a good idea to separate input, processing, and output into (at least) three different methods, *especially* when you're learning.  It's vastly easier to understand a bunch of short methods than one do-it-all method, and makes debugging problems like this *much* easier.

Comment: wow this is awesome thank you for this in-depth explanation i appreciate it a lot! thanks for the tips too , some good valid points that will help me in the future hopefully.

Comment: @ShkumbinDelija:  Also, some of these errors would have been _much_ easier to spot with consistent indentation, spacing, and naming.  That sort of discipline will pay for itself many times over.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `CountQiftPositiv(x)` outside of the while loop.

With the code you have, it's the same thing as you call `CountQiftPositiv(-9999)`

I'm suggesting you to do something like:

```
do {
  System.out.print("Type numbers (-9999 to end) : ");
  x = scan.nextInt();
  if(x == SENTINEL) {
    break;
  }
  if (CountQiftPositiv(x) > 0) { 
    count++;
  }
} while (x != SENTINEL);
```

I suggest also to rework your loop since the `break` is not required if you use the `x = scan.nextInt();` wisely.

Answer (score 1):

You have return `0` because last input is `-9999` a negative number, and this condition `if(nr % 2 == 0 && nr % 3 == 0 && nr > 0)` is usually `false`.
Try to change the `SENTINEL` nymber:

Answer (score 1):

`CountQiftPositiv(x)` sends `-9999` in because its the last x value always -> as you stop taking inputs when `x = -9999`

`nr < 0` -> `poz` will stay at 0

I've made a `temp` variable which will take your input, if the input is not equal to the `SENTINEL` variable, it will set `x = temp` thus removing the `-9999` value from being passed into `CountQiftPositiv()`.

Also when you are checking for a number that is a factor for multiple numbers, all you have to do is multiply the numbers together and check the mod for that number.

For `2` and `3`, all you have to check is `6`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class QiftPositivCount {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        final int SENTINEL = -9999;
        int temp;
        int x = 0;
        int count = 0;
        do {
            System.out.print("Type numbers (-9999 to end) : ");
            if((temp = scan.nextInt()) == SENTINEL){
                break;
            }else {
                x = temp;
                count++;
            }  

        } while (temp != SENTINEL); // not really needed as you have the break statement

        if (count == 0) {
            System.out.println("You didnt type any number");

        } else {
            System.out.println("There are " + count + " numbers typed , and the numbers that fulfill the conditon are "
                    + CountQiftPositiv(x)); // This was sending -9999 which will always evaluate to false in the function
            //poz will stay at 0 the entire time
        }

    }

    private static int CountQiftPositiv(int nr) {
        int poz = 0;
        //if(nr % 6 && nr > 0){
        if (nr % 2 == 0 && nr % 3 == 0 && nr > 0) {
            poz++;
        }
        return poz;
    }
}
```

Comment: @ShkumbinDelija No problem, I added another segment about finding factors.